# How to shutdown ExecutorService in Resteasy

Tags: java, servlets, threadpool, resteasy, executorservice

I have a servlet that has an **ExecutorService** that makes HTTP requests to multiple destinations.
I'm not sure how I shutdown the ExecutorService. I don't have `destroy()` method in Resteasy?

```
@Path("ops")
public class Dashboard{

ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

@GET
@Path("data")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getDataFromDCs(){
  try{
    threadExecutor.invokeAll(jobWorkers, 6000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }catch(Exception e){}
  finally{
  //should call threadExecutor.shutdown() here? 
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that shutdown() is not present? Are you using https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/servlet/HttpServletDispatcher.html? That class has destroy() and you can call threadExecutor.shutdown()

Comment: I use Resteasy Singleton style to wraps my endpoints. HttpServletDispatcher is defined in the web.xml:
<servlet>
       <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>
           org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
       </servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
           <param-value>com.company.WSApplication</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </servlet>

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Singleton Class that will have executor Service logic initiated , a destroy method and a service(jobWorker,int time,TimeUnit timeunit). Then write a Listener implementing HTTPServletListener and in contextDestroyed call the destroy method of the singleton class. This will save you from reinitiating executor on each service call and you can safely shutdown the executor on application shutdown. and in the webservice class in `getDataFromDCs()` get the instance of the singleton class and call it's `service` method passing the arguments.

Comment: Do I really have to shutdown the ExecutorService when I shut down the server? Can ExecutorService live after server process is killed?

Comment: Yes you need to properly shutdown it, try with a simple program and dont add .shutdown in last you will see that the threads in debug will still live.

Answer (score 0):

you can call shutdown method of the threadExecutor. But it does not guarantee that all the task will finish. You should also use awaitTermination, for example:

```
while( !executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ) {
    LOGGER.info("Awaiting completion of threads.");
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)